# What happens if the snakemake threads directive does not match the number of threads defined within shell directive?

Tags: multithreading, snakemake

If the snakemake threads directive is not used properly, does the command still run in parallel?

Case 1, threads are not sufficient:

```py
rule someRule:
    ...
    threads: 2
    benchmark: "benchmark.out"
    shell: 
        "sometool --threads 3"
```

Case 2, threads not defined:

```py
rule someRule:
    ...
    benchmark: "benchmark.out"
    shell: 
        "sometool --threads 2"
```

As far as I understand from [snakemake advanced tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/advanced.html), `threads` will only define the expectation for snakemake to help it schedule when to submit how many jobs, and a job can still be multithreaded in these cases; so the benchmarks for the multithreading are valid. Is this correct? Can you help me understand it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, threads in the snakemake rule definition are used just for a scheduling of jobs. However, the best practice would be if this property and argument in the command executed do match.

Regarding benchmark. In your example this might not be quite right. Consider whole pipeline and jobs running in parallel. Depending on how many threads you allocate for a certain rule, benchmark might be different. Let's take as an example your second case. Let's assume that you allow to run 8 jobs in parallel for snakemake and that you have 8 threads available on your CPU. What would happen? 8 jobs would be started, meanwhile each of those jobs would try to use 2 threads. It would run and it would complete but benchmark will be incorrect for this particular task.